# How to implement a custom tag in tornado templating

Tags: python, django, tornado, templating

I have a situation where i need to do some logics inside the template. I found that i can pass the function with the controller but my problem needs exact solutions like below. Anyone there to help me sort it.?

eg: index.html

```
{% code %}
  def sum(a, b):
      return a + b
{% end %}
<body>
   <b>Sum:</b> {{ sum(10, 20)  }}
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tornado's template system does not support defining multi-line functions inside the template. In simple cases you can use `{% set f = lambda... %}` but all other functions must come from outside the template (either passed in via the namespace or imported within the template with the `{% import %}` directive).

Comment: Thank you @Ben Darnell. But is there any other templating which supports my request?